# How to Get text box id on run time in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I had made a test case in Selenium IDE But When I play this test case with different input it failed because id of textbox change At Start it was **ctl03** after inserting record it changed to **ctl04**

My Question Is

> How can I change the id of textbox automatically?

OR

> how can I read id of the text box on runtime?

if I change this manually it is consuming too much time

[image]

Comment: what do you mean I didn't get it?

Comment: @SaadSaghir he meant for you to show the actual html, if it is public the url, or copy the html file into pastebin

Comment: @eLRuLL how can I show him actual HTML?

Comment: @SaadSaghir, Just add your element HTML snippet  like `<input id="ct000" class="abc"/>` something. So we can help you out.

Comment: @Tuks Check it now

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector to handle dynamic content: Use below CSS path

```
css=a[id^='ctl100ContentPlaceHolder_gridGenSetup'][id$='lnkSave']
```

Explanation :

Here It will locate the element. the id which have `ctl100ContentPlaceHolder_gridGenSetup` starting with and `lnkSave` end with

**Note:** replace your tag in the path here i m using `a` tag